# Pyspark AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split''

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, apache-spark-ml

I am working on a Pyspark using the flatMap function and I am using the split within the function. But I am getting an error which says:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split''

I am watching a video and replicating the same thing I am seeing in the video. It works in the video but I keep getting this error. Below is my code:

```
 datasetfor2019.map(lambda col: col[Conditions])\
.filter(lambda x: x!='')\
.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(','))\
.map(lambda x: (x, 1))\
.reduceByKey(add)\
.sortBy(lambda x: x[1], ascending=False)\
.take(5)
```

I will like to know what I am doing wrong or if I need to import anything into my Pyspark environment, what could that be?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Are some values of your column `null`? The error seems to point in that direction

Comment: you can easily debug the problem by print the result (e.g. rdd.take(5)) after each step. It is difficult to judge in which step the problem arises, as no description to the input data is given.

Comment: I seem not to know where the null is and I have tried to flag it in my condition but its not seem to be working out.

Comment: @XYZ I will check that and see how this works out

Comment: .filter(lambda x: x!='')\ wont filter null values...

Comment: @SakuraFreak would you please mind letting me know what would filter the null values? Perhaps that is where the error is coming from. Thank you in advance

Comment: @olammy not sure if I'm correct since I don't have the possibility of testing it right now, but it should be something along the lines of `.filter(lambda x: x is not None)`

Comment: This question is more about  about python serialization than Spark itself, since you're using rdd. Using map you may get null values inside tuples, which a null value won't heritage string object, thus not being able to call String.split("") method